# Char array to Int Conversion

Tags: c, memory, endianness

working on a new project and encountered a problem.
I got a chunk of bytes in a char array.
There are 4 bytes in Big Endian that I need to convert to int.
When I try to convert from 4 bytes char array to int byte byte after byte, on of them turns up in a negative form.
Any solutions/algorithms?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code. Note, that `char` might be signed by default, so you might want to explicitly work with `unsigned char`

Answer (score 1):

Networking code? This is what `ntohl` and `htonl` are for. These functions convert between native endian and big endian.

To read an integer:

```
 int value = (int) ntohl(*(int32_t *)(buffer + offset));
```

To write an integer:

```
 *((int32_t *)(buffer + offset)) = htonl((int32_t)value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use atoi to convert your array.

[atoi man](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

To use atoi you need your array to end with a "\0" but you can do:

- strncpy to copy n bytes to a temporary buffer.
- add "\0" at the end of the tmp buffer.
- use atoi on this temporary buffer.

You can repeat above actions inside a loop and choose the number of bytes you want to convert with strncpy paramaters (n)

[strncpy man](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)